# Python Sort values by first list in 2D array containing list and value

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, 2d

I am keeping track of a list, and each set has a percent support (percentage value indicating frequency). Each support is tied to one set.

x:

```
[('C', 'A'), 66.667]
[('T', 'A'), 50.0]
[('C', 'D'), 66.667]
[('C', 'T'), 66.667]
[('C', 'W'), 83.333]
[('A', 'W'), 66.667]
[('W', 'T'), 50.0]
[('W', 'D'), 50.0]
```

I would like the array sorted, ignoring the support so that it looks like this:

```
[('A', 'C'), 66.667]
[('A', 'T'), 50.0]
[('A', 'W'), 66.667]
[('C', 'D'), 66.667]
[('C', 'T'), 66.667]
[('C', 'W'), 83.333]
[('D', 'W'), 50.0]
[('T', 'W'), 50.0]
```

sort the sets in x[0] then the entire first column

Comment: Check out the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the tuples, then sort the list:

```
lst = sorted([[tuple(sorted(x)), y] for x, y in lst], key=lambda x: x[0])
print(lst)
```

---

```
[[('A', 'C'), 66.667], 
 [('A', 'T'), 50.0], 
 [('A', 'W'), 66.667], 
 [('C', 'D'), 66.667], 
 [('C', 'T'), 66.667], 
 [('C', 'W'), 83.333], 
 [('D', 'W'), 50.0], 
 [('T', 'W'), 50.0]]
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the key for your outer call to `sorted`.

Comment: @ZachGates Oh yes, I do. I don't want to assume the tuples will never tie, in which case a keyless sort will break ties using the percentage, which is not what they want.

Comment: Fair enough. After reading the question again, OP did say to ignore the percentage. Good answer.